# TFS on Visual Studio 2010 : can't modify files a colleague extracted

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a quite annoying issue with TFS.
My colleague extracted source code files on Visual Studio 2010, but didn't checked them in before he takes days off, consequently I can't modify them,
Is there any solution to force the access ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo another user’s checkout in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690520/how-to-undo-another-user-s-checkout-in-tfs)

Comment: As a thought: your environment is *over a decade old*. Switching to newer technology (git on TFS and maybe VS2022 or at least 2019) will solve those problems in the future.