# TFS Check out issue

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

I have checked out one file in tfs from my workspace, but by mistake new OS was updated without check in that file in tfs, after all the set up i cant able to check in that file

And no pending check ins also showing

How to check in that file in tfs, please provide any solution for this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo another user’s checkout in TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690520/how-to-undo-another-user-s-checkout-in-tfs)

Answer (score 1):

This item usually locked. Choose one of below ways to resolve it.

1) You can using below command to undo the pending changes:

```
tf undo "file_path" /workspace:workspace_name
```

2) Or you can just use below command to delete the old workspace

```
tf workspace /delete /server:your_tfs_server workspace;username
```

From Visual Studio 2015 GUI：

```
File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces...
```

In the dialog that came up, check "Show remote workspaces" and the locked workspace came up in the window. Then selected it and click "Remove".

3) Or try to use the free [TFS Sidekick application](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/). It has an option to view and undo other user's checkout.

---

Details about it, please check this [blog](http://www.mikebevers.be/blog/2009/07/tfs-undo-checkout-or-lock-by-another-user/) and more ways to resolve this you can refer the similar question: [What do you do if the file in TFS is locked by someone else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268865/what-do-you-do-if-the-file-in-tfs-is-locked-by-someone-else)